# How to publish batched messages to a pubsub topic with retrying request

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, batch-processing, publish-subscribe, retrying

I've read all this doc : https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher there are 3 examples:

1. Publishing to topic
2. Publishing with batch mode
3. Publishing with retrying requests

I want to combine example 2 and 3 into single so publishing with batch mode works with retrying requests.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object `pubsub_v1.PublisherClient` accepts both parameters as input for the construction.

By including the two optional parameters `batch_settings` and `client_config` you can configure batch mode with retrying requests.

```py
from google.cloud import pubsub_v1

publisher_client = pubsub_v1.PublisherClient(
    # Optional Batch param
    batch_settings = pubsub_v1.types.BatchSettings(
        max_bytes=1024,  # One kilobyte
        max_latency=1,   # One second
    ),

    # Optional Retrying param
    client_config = {
        "interfaces": {
            "google.pubsub.v1.Publisher": {
                "retry_params": {
                    "messaging": {
                        'total_timeout_millis': 650000,  # default: 600000
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },

    # Optional
    client_options = {
        "api_endpoint": REGIONAL_ENDPOINT
    }
)
```